# Use managed objects in pure native code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unmanaged, managed

Here I go:
I have a codebase which was written in Linux(C++) and which was moved to Windows. I used CMake to get the sln file. I opened the sln file in Visual Studio 2010 and built the project with "no  clr support option".

Now I have a amanaged dll. I want to create and use the objects of the classes contained in that dll. I did a lot of googling and went through 3-4 tutorials like:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35041/Mixing-NET-and-native-code
but it did not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to write a COM Callable Wrapper (CCW) for the managed DLL.
This will make the managed object look like a COM object to native code.
You can then use the managed object just like using a COM server.

Here is a link about CCW - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx

This link will give you references to all other things needed to do this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439.aspx